# Rails 3.1 Database should be a Mongo::DB, not String. (Mongoid::Errors::InvalidDatabase)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, passenger

i get this **passenger** error.

Full error page: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1725428/stackoverflow/Mongoid-Errors-InvalidDatabase.html

My setup is:
- Mac OSX Lion
- rvm ruby v1.9.3p194
- passenger
- mongodb local server
- rails 3.1.1
- mongoid 2.4.10

This setup worked well, until i tried changing a Rails version in Gemfile from 3.1.1 to 3.2. Then it broke up with *"Database should be a Mongo::DB, not String. (Mongoid::Errors::InvalidDatabase)"*

Tried to use previous rails 3.1.1., but the error persisted.
Tried to reinstall rvm and all the gems. But this still occur.
Tried to use the latest mongoid instead of previous working 2.4.5, not helping though.
Database server is running.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it was bug in the mongoid gem, i used the current 3.0rc right from github and it is working.
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git